# Retrieving version APP_DATA from Tridion_cm with Core Service

Tags: core-service, application-data

I'm developing an extension which saves some Page data (on the Save/SaveClose/SaveNew event) to the `app_data` table throught Core Service Client with the follow code:

```
Byte[] byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(applicationData);
ApplicationData appData = new ApplicationData
{
    ApplicationId = "AppData:Page",
    Data = byteData,
    TypeId = "-64"
};
_client.SaveApplicationData(tcmElement, new[] { appData });
```

It works fine, but when I reload the Page the data that I get is wrong, because is data stored in a previous version of the item in the `app_data` table...
I read the data following this code:

```
ApplicationData appData = _client.ReadApplicationData(tcmElement, "AppData:Page");*
```

Do you know what could be the problem? Is there any way to get a specific version of the data in `app_data`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SaveApplicationData` method saves Application Data on the (version of) the item you specify as first parameter.

Note that a TCM URI can contain a version number (`-v{version}` suffix). In case of a *Versioned Item*, a TCM URI without version implicitly addresses the latest, checked-in version. If you want to add App Data to a checked-out item (which will be checked-in later), you should use the *Dynamic Version*, which has a `-v0` suffix in its TCM URI.